# Pandas Pivot_table error when executing -Type error

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm new to Pandas and is testing and learning. Have the following problem with a dataframe imported from Excel:
- The dataframe contains the following variables:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 48062 entries, 0 to 48061
Data columns (total 11 columns):
Konskund_MEAB         48062  non-null values
Strukturordn          48062  non-null values
Antal_forsandelser    48062  non-null values
ProdID                48062  non-null values
Sort                  48062  non-null values
Storstad              48062  non-null values
Year                  48062  non-null values
snittvikt             48062  non-null values
Totsum                48062  non-null values
Prodsum               48062  non-null values
snittpris             48062  non-null values
dtypes: float64(9), object(2)
```

- Running:

  `np.average(df['snittpris'],weights=df['Antal_forsandelser'])`

produce the correct result

- When I try running a pivot_table using the following command:

  `df_sum=pd.pivot_table(df,rows=['Konskund_MEAB','ProdID'],cols=['Year'],
  aggfunc=np.average(df ['snittpris'],weights=df['Antal_forsandelser']))`

I get the following error messages.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-9fd03896c806> in <module>()
----> 1 df_sum=pd.pivot_table(df,rows=['Konskund_MEAB','ProdID'],cols=['Year'],
aggfunc=np.average(df['snittpris'],weights=df['Antal_forsandelser']))

C:\Users\Bengtw\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\pivot.pyc
in pivot_table(data, values, rows, cols, aggfunc, fill_value, margins, dropna)
    101 
    102     grouped = data.groupby(keys)
--> 103     agged = grouped.agg(aggfunc)
    104 
    105     table = agged

C:\Users\Bengtw\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc
 in agg(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
342     @Appender(_agg_doc)
343     def agg(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
--> 344         return self.aggregate(func, *args, **kwargs)
345 
346     def _iterate_slices(self):

C:\Users\Bengtw\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc
 in aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs)
   1741 
   1742             if self.grouper.nkeys > 1:
-> 1743                 return self._python_agg_general(arg, *args, **kwargs)
   1744             else:
   1745                 result = self._aggregate_generic(arg, *args, **kwargs)

C:\Users\Bengtw\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc
 in _python_agg_general(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    480 
    481         if len(output) == 0:
--> 482             return self._python_apply_general(f)
    483 
    484         if self.grouper._filter_empty_groups:

C:\Users\Bengtw\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc
 in _python_apply_general(self, f)
    332 
    333     def _python_apply_general(self, f):
--> 334         keys, values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, self.obj, self.axis)
    335 
    336         return self._wrap_applied_output(keys, values,

C:\Users\Bengtw\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc
 in apply(self, f, data, axis, keep_internal)
    628             # group might be modified
    629             group_axes = _get_axes(group)
--> 630             res = f(group)
    631             if not _is_indexed_like(res, group_axes):
    632                 mutated = True

C:\Users\Bengtw\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc
 in <lambda>(x)
    468     def _python_agg_general(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
    469         func = _intercept_function(func)
--> 470         f = lambda x: func(x, *args, **kwargs)
    471 
    472         # iterate through "columns" ex exclusions to populate output dict

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

What is the problem?? The row variable Konskund_MEAB contains strings (a few hundred different), ProdID is numerical and have 4 unique values. Year is what it is (4 discrete values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument `aggfunc` should be a *function*, but you are passing in a float.
Hence the TypeError:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

You can pass in an anonymous (lambda) function, which *may* be what you are after:

```
aggfunc=lambda x: np.average(x['snittpris'], weights=x['Antal_forsandelser'])
```

*Unfortunately this doesn't work in this case (since the `aggfunc` doesn't have access to unused columns)...*

Instead you could use a [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html):

```
rows = ['Konskund_MEAB','ProdID']
cols = ['Year']
g = df.groupby(rows + columns)
```

and apply the function to each group, and then [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) from a Series to a DataFrame:

```
s_av = g.apply(lambda x: np.average(x['snittpris'], weights=x['Antal_forsandelser']))
df_av = s_av.unstack(cols)
```

Comment: I think it's `aggfunc`, as per your other answer regarding **color** :).

Comment: Tried your suggestion which seems to be what I want. Get a new set of error messages ending with "KeyError: 'snittpris'"

Comment: @user1160760 hmmm this function doesn't seem to have access to the column, also seem to get something involving SNDArray... very strange. :(

Comment: Andy: Thank you very much for the help! Don't really understand why your first solution didn't  work out.  Can you explain your comment about aggfunc not having access to unused columns?

Comment: @user1160760 Not sure I do fully either, I think I should probably put it up as an issue on github to discuss/fix, suspect it is untested behaviour, but it seemed that you can only apply aggfunc to columns which were going to be in your pivot_table (IIRC the rest are not passed to the function so couldn't be used), also I was seeing SNDArrays which was confusing... I need to investigate a further.

Comment: Definitely seems like unintended behavior / bug. Will you post on github?

Comment: Have previously used R and library Plyr to do similar analyses but pandas/ipython seem like a very attractive alternative. The syntax of Pandas is quite straightforward (if working ...)

Comment: @user1160760 thanks for posting on github: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4733 (perhaps we're missing something obvious :) )